# На долго ― это правильно?

Tags: орфография, предлоги, слитно-раздельно

Может ли предлог НА относиться к наречию в сочетании ***на долго***?

**Примеры:**

Но нам туда и не надо. Нам вообще там **на долго** зависать нельзя. [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]

Но **на долго ли** хватит ее упорства?  [Константин Серафимов. Экспедиция во мрак (1978-1996)]

В конце года я дам несколько прощальных концертов и **на долго,** а может быть и навсегда, покину эстраду. [Геннадий Алексеев. Зеленые берега (1983-1984)]

Так что если не боитесь трудностей, если готовы изменить всю свою жизнь и **не на две недели, а на долго (на годы)**, то я открою новую тему и напишу (2007-2010).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

[http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=НАДОЛГО](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%93%D0%9E)

Вопрос № 265906

Временное наречие НАДОЛГО пишется слитно. Скажите, а есть какой-то вариант употребления НА **в качестве предлога со словом ДОЛГО?**

Ответ справочной службы русского языка: **Подходящий контекст нам придумать не удалось.**

Так что, всё дело в контексте? В принципе такая возможность не отрицается?

А вот все учебные сайты очень уверенно рассказывают, что, конечно же, наречие ***надолго*** пишется слитно с приставкой НА. **Но это с приставкой...**

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что единственный оправданный случай раздельного написания возникает тогда, когда "долго" номинализируется по смыслу, аналогично "далёку" - как в последнем примере.

В примере из Д. Глуховского стилистически удачнее было бы выразиться "**подолгу** (зависать)" - "надолго" и в правильном написании не подходит из-за неясности: "надолго зависать" или "надолго нельзя будет предаваться этому занятию". Остальное выглядит как ошибки.

Comment: А если и в последнем слитно написать? Я бы так и написал. Или уж "...а на долгое время (на годы)".

Comment: В последнем примере тоже слитно должно бы писаться, но авторская оговорка в скобках может оправдать  специфический акцент на сроке.

Comment: !00 примеров из Нацкоруса обычной ошибкой не назовешь, даже исключив написания, в которых НА относится к определяемому существительному в сложных словосочетаниях. А в старых текстах  раздельное написание вообще было нормой, например: "На другой день князь Андрей вспомнил вчерашний бал, но не на долго остановился на нем мыслями". Мне, кстати, приснился вещий сон с ответом, как Менделееву, но перед эти в голове загорелся  красный квадратик, как на форуме (а это уже клиника). Я "ответ" пока не озвучиваю, хочется услышать другие версии, кроме той, что "это ошибка".

Comment: Я до этого не видел в "корпусе" цитирования форумов, да ещё столь массового (возможно, кто-то из вносителей личным исследованием занялся). Допустим, без отсеивания журналистики найдётся 30 твёрдых примеров - на них приходится 7900 случаев стандартного написания (источники типа "форум" среди них на глаза не попадаются).

Comment: Alex_ander, а Вам ни о чем не говорят такие факты. (1) Не правда ли? - при наличии вопросительной частицы   ЛИ  написание всегда раздельное. Сравнить: на долго ли? (2) Я приехал не на долго, а на пару дней. При противопоставлении предлог НА повторяется (не на длительное время, а на...). 3) Ты на долго приехал? Смысл может быть такой: ты на сколько дней приехал, а не только такой: ты приехал на длительное время.  Две формы написания вроде бы могут иметь различный смысл.

Comment: Два разных смысла должны и по тексту различаться. С противопоставлением: "Я приехал не надолго, _а_ на пару дней"; с уточнением: "Я приехал ненадолго, _всего_ на пару дней".

Comment: Ну да, правильно, должны. Я вот считаю, что выбор слитного или раздельного написание НЕ тоже должно по тексту определяться, а не только по правилам (мы уже в устном тексте должны понимать, где отрицание, а где утверждение, а не рыться в справочниках). Да только этот факт существование дух форм с разным смыслом не отменяет.

Comment: В устной форме смысл должен не по "пробелам" выявляться, а по словам (в этом смысле "по _тексту_"). Чисто интонационные различия в таких выражениях делают речь неестественной, похожей на тост с многозначительными паузами и ударениями.

Comment: Русская речь очень красива,  выразительна, музыкальна, а ее интонацию нужно научиться слушать и понимать. А потом нужно научиться записывать с помощью знаков препинания.

Answer (score 1):

[Словарь русского языка XVIII в.](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/) фиксирует три варианта написания наречия *надолго* — слитно, раздельно и через дефис. Но в заголовке словарной статьи написано слитно.

Для начала отмечу, что ранее первое значение прилагательного "долгий" имело отношение к расстоянию ("длинный"), а не ко времени. Сейчас это значение отмечается в словарях как устаревшее. Но образованное от такого значения наречие **долго** будет писаться с предлогом НА только раздельно. Например:

> Интересно смотреть на долго тянущиеся многоэтажные пригородные дома... (Юрий Трифонов)

Кроме того, можно отметить несколько очевидных случаев с "временным" значением слова **долго**, когда НА, очевидно, не может быть приставкой. Например, если речь идёт о **долго живущих** или **долго действующих** объектах, на которых что-то происходит (или на которые мы смотрим). В научных и научно-популярных изданиях можно встретить множество примеров.

> *... Крупные астероиды **на долго** живущих орбитах* (Астрономия, реферативных журнал)
>
> *Только **на долго** живущих спутниках, этих космических ковчегах, где функционирует замкнутый экологический цикл, мы добились чего-то подобного.* (Н.Н. Семёнов, Избранные произведения).
>
> *В работе обсуждаются различные механизмы рассеяния радиоволн **на долго** живущих (устойчивых) метеорных ионизированных следах.* (Астрономический журнал)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я чуть позже напишу комментарий.

Comment: Прочитала я Ваш ответ, но во всех ваших примеры предлог НА относится к существительному, а между ними находится сложное определение наречие + прилагательное/причастие.  У меня же был вопрос о предлоге НА, который относится именно к наречию.

Comment: @Sharon, Вы правы, я был невнимателен и мой ответ попал мимо. В таком случае я присоединяюсь к банальному мнению, что на сегодняшний день допустимо только слитное написание.